# How to migrate newly added python class property in ndb model?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I currently have a model in NDB and I'd like to add a new property to it. Let's say I have the following:

```
class User(Model, BaseModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)

    @property
    def user_roles(self):
        return UserRole.query(ancestor=self.key).fetch()

    @property
    def roles(self):
        return [user_role.role for user_role in UserRole.query(ancestor=self.key).fetch()]
```

Now, let's say, I've added one additional `property` called `market_id`. For example,

```
class User(Model, BaseModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=False)

    @property
    def user_roles(self):
        return UserRole.query(ancestor=self.key).fetch()

    @property
    def roles(self):
        return [user_role.role for user_role in UserRole.query(ancestor=self.key).fetch()]

    @property
    def market_id(self):
        """ fetches `id` for the resource `market` associated with `user` """
        for each_role in UserRole.query(ancestor=self.key):
            resource = each_role.role.get().resource
            if resource.kind() == 'Market':
                return resource.id()

        return None
```

The problem here is, `roles` are fetched properly as expected for all the existing entities (since that property had been there since the beginning and also, an extra column can be observed in datastore called `roles`).

Since, I'm dealing with Python class property, I assume that migration is not required. But, how does column called `roles` already exist? And why newly added property called `market_id` does not? Does it require migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change you're suggesting is not an actual `ndb` model change as you're not adding/deleting/modifying any of the model's datastore properties. Only `ndb.Property` class children are **real** `ndb` model properties that are stored when the entity is put() into the datastore.

The property you're adding is a Python class @property - nothing to do with what's in the datastore.

So for this particular case no migration is needed.

The update to the question makes this even more clear, I believe. The `market_id` @property is not a `User` datastore entity property. To get values for it you don't need to update the `User` entity, but you have to create/edit corresponding `UserRole` entities with their `resource` property point to a `Market` entity.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I've rephrased my original problem. I wonder how an existing Python class @property called `roles` already reflects in datastore. I'm viewing column called `roles` via query  by GQL `SELECT * from User`. And newly added Python class property `market_id` does not reflect that way.

Comment: That means you have (or had at some point when at least some of the `User` entities were created) some entity property (i.e. a child of the `ndb.Property` class)  named  `roles`. Just like `name` and `email`. That's not the same as the @property `roles`.

Comment: Thank you Dan! This helps. I hope I've improved question content to good general understanding for people.